# Split and merge text

Tags: c++

I need to pass some data from one application to the other and the only way I can do this is by loging data as text and parsing captured log from the othe app.

Right now I am creating an xml with some unique text and extracting it from log using boost regexp. The problem is, xml is too big and loging isn't synchronized which results in my message split into parts(usualy 3, but it can differ). I can force it to log into file, which seems to fix spliting, but now log message is limited to some character number and I can't read it all.

What would be the best way to split data into parts and merge it back later?

I came up with an idea to split it into more xmls with some char limit, ex.

```
<part><nr>1</nr><data>...</data></part>
```

and so on. But this looks like a bit of work, spliting string, finding all parts, merging. Is there a better way to do this or maybe some library has it worked out? It doesn't have to be fool prof, more like quick and clean solution (and mine, in my opinion, sadly isn't).

I can use c++ with limited c11 support and whole boost. Also first application (which sends data) is written in javascript if that helps.

Moreover I'm not very attached to xml it's just human readable, json or something else would be as good.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: "the only way I can do this is by loging data as text and parsing captured log from the othe app" No it's not. Your problem is that you are transferring the data the wrong way. Limitations like this would not exist if you used, say, a file.

Comment: believe me I spend 2 days trying other ways and its either impossible, I just cant do that or it would take so much work its not worth it

Comment: Have you tried *sockets*?

Comment: Why not filter with a regexp *before* logging?

Answer (score 0):

I prefer XML because it's well structured and well supported. I've used the expat xml parser (http://expat.sourceforge.net/) with great success.  It's lightweight and cross platform.